# Windows Azure VM instances. Control by Java

Tags: java, azure

Is there in `azure-sdk-for-java` methods for VM remote control (*start, stop*)? I can control **storages** and **containers** using this SDK. But VM instances maintaining is enabled only from deployed application on VM (*`RoleEnvironment` class*).

In that case only [**REST API**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157206.aspx) can be used to **remote** control VM instances. Am I right?

Comment: I would ask Azul. If they don't know, no one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - according to the [Azure javadocs](http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/), there is nothing outside of the **REST API** at this time. I'd expect the java-SDK to eventually support a managed wrapper, but there isn't one today.